# How to upload image to AWS S3 and get the image file's S3 bucket url and save to dynamodb all at once - Android

Tags: android, url, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

How can I save image to AWS S3 bucket and then retrieve the image public url and save the url into dynamodb alongside other user input data without the user leaving the activity or fragment?
Can all these be achieved at once?
Any sample code example will help a lot. Thanks!!

Comment: The s3 url can be constructed based on the region, bucket and path. Its always the same construction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response :D

Comment: Hey @Sbruce Can you post here full example of upload image from lambda function or android and save url to dynamodb?

Comment: I have explained below how I saved image to S3. I am not sure how to use lambda functions yet. For saving url to DynamoDB I used the DynamoDB mapper class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I upload images to S3:

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = 
             new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
             context.getApplicationContext(),
             YOUR_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
             Regions.US_EAST_1);

AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);

TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client, context.
                      getApplicationContext());

TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
       MY_BUCKET,           // The S3 bucket to upload to
       OBJECT_KEY,   // The key for the uploaded object 
       FILE_TO_UPLOAD // The location of the file to be uploaded );
```

Have this in your manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

 <service android:name= "com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService" android:enabled="true" />
```

[Information source here](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2KF0YUQITA164/AWS-SDK-for-Android-Transfer-Manager-to-Transfer-Utility-Migration-Guide)

I made the folder in S3 bucket public and saved the file link in dynamoDB like this:
"https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myfolder/myimage.jpg"

-

Answer (score 5):

Try this code -

```
private void uploadImageToAWS() {

        AsyncTask<String, String, String> _Task = new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {


            }



            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) 
            {

                if (NetworkAvailablity.checkNetworkStatus(PrintRollScreenActivity.this)) 
                {
                    try {
                        java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
                        long msec = expiration.getTime();
                        msec += 1000 * 60 * 60; // 1 hour.
                        expiration.setTime(msec);
                        publishProgress(arg0);

                        String existingBucketName = "YOUR_AWS_BUCKET_NAME";////////////
                        String keyName = "image_name";
                        String filePath = "";

                        AmazonS3Client s3Client1 = new AmazonS3Client( new BasicAWSCredentials( "AWS_KEY","AWS_SECRET") );
                        PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(existingBucketName,
                                keyName + ".png",new File(filePath));//key is  URL

                        //making the object Public
                        por.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
                        s3Client1.putObject(por);


                        String _finalUrl = "https://"+existingBucketName+".s3.amazonaws.com/" + keyName + ".png";

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // writing error to Log
                        e.printStackTrace();


                    }




                } 
                else
                {

                }


                return null;

            }
            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                System.out.println("Progress : "  + values);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
            {

            }
        };
        _Task.execute((String[]) null);


    }
```

Comment: this url is not public accessible.

Answer (score 3):

Every object in S3 can have either a private or public access permissions.

If it's public then the public URL is always `http(s)://s3(-region).amazonaws.com/BUCKET/KEY` so that's phase 1.

If you upload synchronously, at the end you can save meta data about that link to DynamoDB and be sure you're fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the your useful response :D